# Cannot send emails to addresses with Scandinavian characters

Tags: c#, .net, email, .net-4.5, smtpclient

Using `SmtpClient`, `MailMessage` and `MailAddress` classes, I cannot send to email addresses such as åbc.def@domain.se. I get the error/exceptions as shown below:

> An invalid character was found in the mail header: 'å'.

> --------------------------- Error sending email
> --------------------------- System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII
> local-parts: åbc.def@domain.se.
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetUser(Boolean allowUnicode)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetAddress(Boolean allowUnicode)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.Encode(Int32 charsConsumed, Boolean
> allowUnicode)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Encode(Int32
> charsConsumed, Boolean allowUnicode)
> at System.Net.Mail.Message.PrepareHeaders(Boolean sendEnvelope,
> Boolean allowUnicode)
> at System.Net.Mail.Message.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean
> sendEnvelope, Boolean allowUnicode)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

These characters in my subject/body are fine, but not in email addresses.

I've tried setting `SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International`, or `MailMessage.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` (or `UTF8`) and it doesn't seem to change anything. These are real email addresses of people we need to communicate with so it's a bit of a problem.

I have been digging through the .Net source code but not really gotten anywhere. I tracked down a `ServerSupportsEai` property, and Google tells me EAI stands for Email Address Internationalisation (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5336) but it's fairly unclear if this is a limitation in my code, or if the specific server I'm talking to just doesn't support this... since I'm using a test server to avoid sending emails to unsuspecting Swedish people!

Can someone help me clear this up - does .Net support this, if so what if anything should my client code do to enable it?

Comment: I think the problem maybe not in .NET code, but in your email server configuration. Can you try using another server?

Comment: (5336 is replaced with 6531/2) This facility requires the smtp server to support SMTPUTF8, try with Gmail which does, if it works its your server thats the issue.

Comment: Thanks. After fighting with gmail "you app doesn't use up to date security and has been blocked" I am testing this - though I still can't actually send to a real person very politely

Comment: Is there a way to see which widely used email servers _do_ support this?

Comment: Maybe [here] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP) you can get some info

Answer (score 16):

To be able to to send UTF-8 characters according to [RFC6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531) both client and server need to support it.

If you use the .NET implementation of `SmtpClient` you'll need to target framework version 4.5 because that implementation supports the SMTPUTF8 extension.

If you set the [`DeliveryFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.deliveryformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property you have done what is needed for your client to support UTF8 characters:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
             
    var message = new MailMessage(
        "my.email@gmail.com",
        "ëçïƒÖ@example.com",
        "UTF8",
        "Is UTF8 supported?");
              
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

If we reverse-engineer the `Send` method we can easily follow the stack-trace from your question. You'll find this implementation:

```
if (!allowUnicode && !MimeBasePart.IsAscii(this.userName, true))
{
    throw new SmtpException(SR.GetString("SmtpNonAsciiUserNotSupported", new object[]
    {
        this.Address
    }));
}
```

That `allowUnicode` boolean is being supplied from the `Send` method:

```
if (this.DeliveryMethod == SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network)
{
    return this.ServerSupportsEai && this.DeliveryFormat == SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
}
```

Now here comes the server in the picture. When does the private boolean `ServerSupportsEai` becomes true? It turns out that on sending the `EHLO` command the `SmptConnection` calls `ParseExtensions`:

```
if (string.Compare(text, 0, "SMTPUTF8", 0, 8, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
    ((SmtpPooledStream)this.pooledStream).serverSupportsEai = true;
}
```

If you want to know upfront if your mail server is supporting that extension you can simply connect with a telnet client (I use putty) to your smtp server and send the `EHLO somename` command and inspect the results.

Connecting to `smtp.gmail.com`on port 587 gives me this output:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP hx10sm19521922wjb.25 - gsmtp
EHLO fubar
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:FFF:8bef:1:34d6:a247:FFFF:4620]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Notice the last line: it holds our required SMTPUTF8

tl;dr

To be able to use international characters in the emailaddres make sure to set the `DeliveryFormat`to `SmtpDeliveryFormat.International` and use an smtp server that supports the SMTPUTF8 extension and advertises it in its `EHLO` command.