# Send internationalized email

Tags: c#, sendgrid

How do I send an email with accented letters? Example is `pepé@lefrenchplace.com`, which should be supported now with [RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532)

If I send an email to `pepé@lefrenchplace.com` from gmail's web interface, it is delivered no problem.

I'm using `.NET 4.6.1`, `C#`, and `SendGrid`.

First attempt with SMTP:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient(Server)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, ApiKey),
    DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International
};

var message = new MailMessage(From, To)
{
    Subject = Subjet,
    Body = BodyPlainText
};

smtp.Send(message);
```

This throws an `SmtpException` with the message `The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: pepé@lefrenchplace.com.`

Second attempt [API V3 with SendGrid C# library](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html)

```
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
var to = new EmailAddress("pepé@lefrenchplace.com", "Example User");
var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

I get an `Accepted` status code returned. On the SendGrid dashboard it shows as Dropped with Invalid as the reason.

Comment: does the server return SMTPUTF8 in its EHLO message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36375833/578411

Comment: @rene It does not return SMTPUTF8 from EHLO. So.. option 1 is out. Would option 2 possibly work some how?

Comment: perhaps it could digest the address if you converted it to IDN, [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101202/1132334)

Comment: @dlatikay No luck. Converts to `xn--peplepew@lefrenchplace-d8b.com`. No SMTP exception though, just doesnt get sent to my inbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit August 2020

SendGrid has closed the Github issue. Anybody wanting a standards compliant email provider to send to an internationalized email address should look elsewhere. [Mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#internationalization) would work

---

As of right now, SendGrid does not support E-mail addresses with non-ASCII local-parts at all.

They told me it is on their radar but have no time commitment for implementation.

[Github issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/656)